# Separate LogManager per Eclipse plugin?

Tags: osgi, classloader, eclipse-plugin, java.util.logging

**How can I choose a separate java.util.Logging.LogManager implementation to be used by my Eclipse plugin, but not by the rest of Eclipse?**

My plugin uses a third party library invoking LogManager.getLogManager(), so I can't pass around my own LogManager instance.

A LogManager implementation can be selected via the java system property "java.util.logging.manager" before the static initializer for the LogManager class is executed, but the LogManager class is loaded by the bootstrap class loader long before my plugin is activated.

I was thinking about using Eclipse-BuddyPolicy or Bundle-ClassPath to have a custom class loader, that would not delegate to the bootstrap class loader and instead load its own copy of the java.util.Logging.LogManager, but classes from java.* packages can normally not be loaded by custom class loaders.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class loader idea might work if you can get around [JDK-6448699 LogManager does not load log handler correctly](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6448699) and [JDK-6878454 LogManager class loading inconsistent with Java EE best practices](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6878454).

The LogManager is suppose to be global for a JVM.  So really you would have to implement your own LogManager that does what you want and have everyone use it.  Eclipse, 3rd party libs, and your plugin shouldn't care which LogManager is installed.